# How to configure socket.timeout in Blender Python script

Tags: python, sockets, blender

When I tried to implement one of my Python scripts in Blender, I noticed that the program remains frozen until it receives data. I read that the exception `socket.timeout` must be used, but I'm not able to configure it. Can someone kindly explain the changes that need to be made?

```
IP_UDP = "192.168.1.102" # Local ip of machine
PORTA_UDP = 12345#local port

sock = socket.socket( socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM )
sock.settimeout(5);

sock.bind( (IP_UDP,PORTA_UDP) )
  # GET VALUE

messaggio, indirizzo = sock.recvfrom( 1024 )
print ("Messaggio ricevuto :", messaggio)
```

Comment: Timeouts are different than waiting for data to be read. If it's hanging on the `recvfrom` when waiting for data; this is not a timeout, it's just waiting. One way to stop the hang is to thread it, have one thread try to read data constantly and put it in a synchronized queue, and the other thread do stuff till data is present, then utilize the new data when it is.

Comment: I get the `timeout` as expected with your code. Something else must be going on.

Comment: PLs,edit my code... don't work